# Line wrap txt file in Intellij

Tags: text-editing, text-formatting, intellij-idea

I'm copying some text from notepad over to intellij. Is there any way to get it to wrap when the lines exceed a certain length?

***Text in notepad***

[image: Text in notepad]

When I copy it in intellij the line just doesn't wrap:

***Text in intellij***

[image: text in intellij]

Even though I've set line wraps in the settings. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Please note that the file type in intellij is *.txt. It's not a code file.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Preferences/Editor/General and choosing "soft wrap".  Seemed to work for me.

Screenshot of preferences
[image]